# JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea, jrebel, jdwp

I have been trying to run with JRebel this configuration:

[image]

[image]

Here is my output:

```
c:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2\bin\run.bat -c default

c:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2\bin>set JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=188.173.32.78 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -DproxySet=true 
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: c:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Dhttp.proxyHost=188.173.32.78 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -DproxySet=true -Dprogram.name=run.bat -server -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

  CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib\tools.jar;c:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2\bin\run.jar

===============================================================================

[2012-07-16 12:32:53,968] Artifact app-ear:ear: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2012-07-16 12:32:53,972] Artifact my-portlet:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Connected to server
[2012-07-16 12:32:54,007] Artifact app-ear:ear: Artifact is deployed successfully
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
Disconnected from server
```

Comment: Check that nothing is using port **8787** before you start debugging with TcpView, netstat or similar tool.

Comment: I had the same issues after using JRebel

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Notice the following start up parameter in your post.

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

There must be some other process occupied the 8787 port.

Comment: how and where to change the port number?

Comment: I know I'm late to this but @yashhy can open the `standalone.bat` (or .sh file) in any editor and there you'll find line **set DEBUG_PORT=8787**. You can edit the port no. there

Answer (score 2):

The **8787** port is already in use.
If the 8787 port in use by another application, you need to select a different port number in file **run.bat**
For example, **18787**

Answer (score 2):

> ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
>   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
>   from "JAVA_OPTS: address=8787"

You set Address 8787

1. Find the PID

   ```
   netstat -ap | grep 8787
   ```
2. If you still see the PID with the above command, then
   there are child PIDs. To find the child PIDs

   ```
   pstree -p
   ```

   and

   ```
   pstree -p  | grep previousPID
   ```
3. Find the groupPID of the PID

   ```
   ps x -o "%r %p %y %x %c"
   ```
4. Kill the found PID

   ```
   kill -TERM -groupPID
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Usually this error occurs when the port is already in use. Based on my experience, this usually happen when the server didn't started successfully making the server still running in the process. If you're using windows, you can check out your Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) and then look for "java.exe" process. Terminate it and try to start your server again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs whenever the port required to run your server is already in use by some other application. Since the port number **8080** which i used for my jetty server was already in use,it gave me this error so I just changed the port from **8080** to **7070** and it worked for me..

Comment: In My case Nothing is running on port 80 n 8080 still getting error : # tailf /var/lib/tomcat7/instance1/logs/catalina.out
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)

Comment: @AshishKarpe Please note that port 80 and 8080 are not the same. See which process is holding the port 8080 in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Check the debug port in your

> standalone.sh

It must have been

```
DEBUG_MODE=true
DEBUG_PORT="8787"
```

Change the **debug mode to false** or pass a new debug port from the new sh file which calls this standalone  `--debug 8788`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this argument was wrong: `address=server4.example.com:8787`  I was trying to run from another server, e.g., `server3.example.com`.